# Possible abuse of GraphQL Mutations

Tags: graphql

I want to pose a question that has been bothering me for quite some time.

A project I am working on has decided (some time ago) to use a UI written in React that communicates with the backend ONLY using GraphQL query/mutations (with all the various Redux, RTK, etc).

Now, as long as it's primarily about fetching data, I don't have major complaints.

The problem is that GraphQL Mutations are used for ANYTHING that doesn't fall under a query.

To give you some examples:

- Need to send an email? => Call a Mutation (which will reply, say, OK or KO, or an error)
- Complex contract that needs to be validated before proceeding? => Call a Mutation that validates the contract and tells me OK or KO.

Both of these mutations DO NOT CHANGE any underlying data - they only perform "actions".

Now, this smells a lot like technology abuse to me (like: GraphQL is the latest trend -> we use it for everything).

Plus, writing a Mutation is much more complex than writing a simple POST endpoint, both on C# and React side...

My questions are:

- have you ever encountered something like this?
- what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue when implementing graphql. And I think we had it because we wanted to use the same principles as REST on our mutations. Which ended up bad, with a lot of overhead on our backing services.

We then tried to see graphql as a "frontend" instead. Anything you (can) do on the frontend will have a functional query or mutation on graphql. We ended up with less frustration. Our mutations were called by the interaction, instead of the resource we were trying to manipulate. For example `addProductToCart` instead of `postCart`. Or `addCouponToCart` instead of `putCartCoupon`. `writeProductReview` instead of `postReview`, etc. The backend/admin either has their own set of mutations, or sometimes we used REST instead.

We also had attached this to our microservices, and used a lot of graphql federation (for microservices which had a graphql endpoint) and backend stitching.

I have to say we had to quit the project due to other reasons than the technology, but it's easy to fall into the REST mindset when using graphql.

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but that's a bit of our journey of using graphql.

Comment: thanks for your insight - here I can see the same pattern, we aren't really leveraging on GraphQL, also because the GraphQL server is called mainly by one single client, so the data can easily be modelled as required...

Comment: The way we used graphql at the end was that the frontend(s) is/are leading in this. The frontend/interaction team need to clarify what interaction is required. The backend team could then stitch this "procedure" into one or many backing services.  While it isn't necessarily required, we also had multiple graphql endpoints (by using the BFF pattern, Backend For Frontend) because sometimes mutations were not Backwards Compatible, and some teams needed more time to update this. 
Although not required, because you can easily add another mutation instead. But then monitoring becomes very important

Answer (score 1):

I think the [GraqhQL docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations) explains very well when to use Mutations vs. Queries:

> In REST, any request might end up causing some side-effects on the
> server, but by convention it's suggested that one doesn't use GET
> requests to modify data.
> GraphQL is similar - technically any query
> could be implemented to cause a data write. However, it's useful to
> establish a convention that any operations that cause writes should be
> sent explicitly via a mutation.

Notes:

> Now, this smells a lot like technology abuse to me (like: GraphQL is the latest trend -> we use it for everything).

I see no abuse. This is just the way to do it in GraphQL.
Usually it's best to stick to conventions. However if you have a really good reason not to follow the conventions, then you should at least be consistent in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - my point here is that the two examples I listed AREN'T mutating ANY kind of data. NO "mutation" happens since nothing is changed. (edited my OP to make this thing more clear)

Comment: Query vs. Mutation is just a convention. So I'd suggest to define simple to understand rules and stick them in your project. If your rules are to use queries only for database reads and mutations for everything else, its okay: After all this is really simple to understand and argue.
Another way to see it is, that e.g. validation also only reads data and does not write anything and has no side-effects. So a query would also be okay.
Sending an e-mail is different IMHO: this should **not** be a query, because it has an important side-effect. e.g. calling this function twice would send 2 mails!